# See list of errors as you type in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been going around the menus in Eclipse SDK Version: 4.2.1 and didn't find a way to expand the Error views so I can see the errors nicely listed.
I see a very narrow possibly Error panel in the right, visible in the picture I attach, but I can't expand it (can't drag the contour to the left) to see what it contains. Just looking for a quick way to fix it if someone has been through the same. Thank you!

[image]

I currently am able to see errors in the Console window if I launch the program "anyway" disregarding the warning that it contains errors (but this seems strange, there should be a way to see erros and warnings in a window as you type):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try steps below:

1. Right Click on the Perspective e.g. `Java` or `Java EE` (displayed in the icon bar towards the top right) and select `reset` option to reset your current perspective
2. `Alt+Shift+Q, X` or `Window > Show View -> General -> Problems` to open the problem view

Comment: Thank you Reimeus and Yogendra Singh very much!

Answer (score 1):

You could open the "Problems" window in Eclipse which displays current compiler errors:

```
Window->Show View->Other...->General->Problems
```